# Android aChartEngine movable Line Chart

Tags: android, achartengine, linechart

I'm using aChartEngine's 0.7.0 charting library for Android.Can anyone help me that how to draw the line chart from left to right to right and eventually moves out of view and how to scroll the chart view to the left?

my code is....

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GraphicalView view;
    private static Thread thread;
    private TimeSeries dataSet = new TimeSeries("Heart Beat Rate");
    private XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.main);       
              LinearLayout layout_eeg1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart1);
                view = getView(this);
                layout_eeg1.addView(view,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                thread = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } 
                        Point p = getDataFromReciver(i);
                        addNewPoint(p);
                        view.repaint();
                    }
                }
            };
            thread.start(); 

      }      
      private static Point getDataFromReciver(int x) {
        return new Point(x, randomData());
    }

    private static int randomData() {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextInt(180);
    }

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public void Point( int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    private int getX() {
        return x;
    }   
     private int getY() {
        return y;
    }
      public MainActivity() {
        mDataset.removeSeries(dataSet);
        mDataset.addSeries(dataSet);


        renderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        renderer.setLineWidth(2);
        double xmax = mRenderer.getXAxisMax();
        mRenderer.setXAxisMin(xmax - 5);
        //renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
        //renderer.setFillPoints(true);
         mRenderer.setShowAxes(false);
        mRenderer.setShowGridX(false); // X grid helps identify values
        mRenderer.setShowLabels(false); // See the values
        mRenderer.setXTitle("Milisecond #");
        mRenderer.setYTitle("HeartBeat");
        mRenderer.removeSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        }
      private GraphicalView getView(Context context) {
        view = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(context, mDataset, mRenderer);
        return view;

    }
    private void addNewPoint(Point p) {
        dataSet.add(p.x, p.y);      
    }
}
```

Comment: I have created a graph which is moving from left to right. But all the line is gathering in the front when the no of line is increased. For that reason i want to scroll the chart view to the right.

Comment: I see, so you've already made your real-time graph but the graph keeps auto-fitting to fit all of the data points and what you want is a fixed x-axis interval that only shows the most recent data points, right?

Comment: Exactly that is what I am wanting. So do you have any perfect solution for that?

Comment: by the way, if you're responding to me and want me to get notified, put `@` and my name in the response, like `@mango`.

Comment: Well i m telling you briefly. i want to move the graph to right and at the same time the chart view will go to left so that it seems like screen is going toward left. @mango

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your chart isn't using time values, then it should be straight-forward. as you know, `achartengine` automatically tries to fit all the points in one graph so the right will always show. since all you want to control what's showing on the left, you could get the max x value, whatever it is, then you set the min less than the interval that you want to display. here mrenderer is the `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer`

btw achartengine has already upgraded its library to 1.0.0

use this thread instead:

```
    thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Point p = getDataFromReciver(i);
                addNewPoint(p);

                if (i > 5) {
                    mRenderer.setXAxisMin(i - 5);
                }

                view.repaint();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
```

Comment: I have updated my question. When I am using mRenderer.setXAxisMin(..) there is nothing in the graph view. Can you help me by giving any sorce code? @mango

Comment: you look like you might have been having issue. just in case, you should know that you can adjust the y axis too like: `mRenderer.setYAxisMax(max);`

Comment: Thanks a lot that is what I was looking for. Can you tell me one another thing like if i want to change the input of the data of this graph dynamically what i have to do? As i am using use it in heart beat monitor. So i have to change the data according to the pulse. @mango

Comment: you don't need `@mango` here, when responding to my answer, just up there. i'm sorry but i couldn't understand. do you mean that you, for example, want to switch between showing heartrate and pulse? or simply inputting this data dynamically to the dataset like is being done here

Comment: I am a very new user of android and stack overflow. I am very much thankful to you for this co-operation. I am developing a heart beat rate monitor where i can show the heart beat rate. But i need a graph of pulse rate where the graph should move according to the users pulse. In that case if user removes his finger from camera the graph will show only a horizontal straight line and if user puts his finger it will show the correct graph. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it just looks you need another graph like you already have, but do event handling to switch which graph to be shown. it shouldn't be too difficult. try to get as far as you can with it and then make a new question (with code) when you run into issue.

Comment: OK.thanks. and new question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683639/graph-with-dynamic-value-in-android)